# Java: How to fill shape from an ArrayList with color?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have an ArrayList of Shapes (Rectangles and Ovals) and I want to paint these shapes. **How do I fill them with color** in the for loop?

My ArrayList is composed of both Rectangles and Ovals. If I do fillRect(color), it paints *all* shapes as Rectangles, and if I do fillOval(color), it paints all shapes as Ovals. How can I fill the Ovals and Rectangles appropriately? The code below only does the outlines.

```
private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
private Shape currentShape; // the shape being drawn (either Rectangle or Oval)

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for(Shape s : shapes) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        s.paint(g2d);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that your `Shape`s are held in an ArrayList is completely irrelevant — your question is really "How to fill a shape with color".

Comment: `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();` should be **outside** the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphics2D.fill(Shape)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill(java.awt.Shape)) will do.

```
private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        g2d.fill(shape);
    }
}
```

No `g.create`. The fact that every paintComponent parameter is actually a Graphics2D is historically founded: they replaced Graphics by a more exhaustive Graphics2D, but for backward compatibility kept Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fill them with color in the for loop?

You need to store the Color information with the Shape. So you need to create a custom object with two properties: "shape" and "color". Then you can set the Graphics Color before you paint the Shape.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.